# return {0} from a function in C?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I got the following discrepancy between compiling as 'C' vs. compiling as 'C++'

```
struct A {
  int x;
  int y;
};

struct A get() {
  return {0};      
}
```

When compiling as 'C++' everything goes fine.
However, when compiling as 'C'; i am getting:

error : expected expression

which i can fix by doing:

```
return (struct A){0};
```

However, i wonder where the difference comes from. Can any one point in the language reference where this difference comes from?

Comment: I would suppose that c++ compiler automatically converts the return value to `struct A`. And in c=+ you don't need `struct A get()` just `A get()`

Comment: Did you try it with a C++ compiler *prior* to C++ 11 ? [Pretty sure it pukes there too](http://ideone.com/PBFlOR).

Comment: Somehow , i think this is directly related to automatic return type deduction introduced in c++11.

Comment: I think that **[this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)** might help. The second half of the paragraph at the given link (starting with "Compound literals for scalar types") answers your question.

Comment: Do you not realise that C and C++ are two _separate_ languages? You might as well try compiling this as PHP then ask what mechanism causes execution failure. Totally barmy!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The two use completely different mechanisms, one of which is C++11-specific, the other of which is C99-specific.

The first bit,

```
struct A get() {
  return {0};
}
```

depends on [stmt.return] (6.6.3 (2)) in C++11, which says

> (...) A return statement with a *braced-init-list* initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization from the specified initializer list. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> std::pair<std::string,int> f(const char *p, int x) {
>   return {p,x};
> }
> ```
>
> -- *end example* ]

This passage does not exist in C (nor C++ before C++11), so the C compiler cannot handle it.

On the other hand,

```
struct A get() {
  return (struct A){0};
}
```

uses a C99 feature called "compound literals" that does not exist in C++ (although some C++ compilers, notably gcc, provide it as a language extension; gcc warns about it with -pedantic). The semantics are described in detail in section 6.5.2.5 of the C99 standard; the money quote is

> 4 A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers is a *compound literal*. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list. (footnote 80)
>
> 80) Note that this differs from a cast expression. For example, a cast specifies a conversion to scalar types or `void` only, and the result of a cast expression is not an lvalue.

So in this case `(struct A){0}` is an unnamed object that is copied into the return value and returned. (note that modern compilers will elide this copy, so you do not have to fear runtime overhead from it)

And there you  have it, chapters and verses. Why these features exist the way they do in their respective languages may prove to be a fascinating discussion, but I fear that it is difficult for anyone outside the respective standardization committees to give an authoritative answer to the question. Both features were introduced after C and C++ split ways, and they're not developed side by side (nor would it make sense to do so). Divergence is inevitable even in small things.

Comment: BTW, What actually `(struct A){0}` is returning? AFAIK, The `return` statement should be `(struct A){0, 0}`.

Comment: @hackks: The stuff that's not mentioned in a braced initializer list is zero-initialized (see 6.7.8 (21) in C99). This happens in normal struct and array initializations as well.

Comment: @Wintermute; That will be the case if `return` statement would be `(struct A){.x = 0}`. And that reference is concerned with array initialization. I am asking this because I am not sure about structures or may be this point is slipped from my memory.

Comment: OK. Found it here: **C99-6.7.8: (p17):** *Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no
designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union*